# SQL query for deposits and withdrawals. With condition the withdrawals after 3 months don't count

Tags: sql, postgresql, analytics

I'm trying to solve this task. But I can't understand how to add 3 months condition right. Please help

Partners receive bonuses for every client that they introduce to the company. Assume that the company has 3 active partners.

Partner paid on a monthly based - for every introduced client partner gets 0.5% of the amount deposited by the client excluding withdrawals. But, with the condition that if the client withdraws the amount more than 3 months after the amount was deposited – such withdrawals are not included in the partner’s bonus reduction.

For example, in August partner’s client deposited $1000 and withdraw $100. Partner gets (1000-100)*0.5%=$4.5. But in case the $100 withdrawal is from the deposit made by the client in April, in this case, the partner’s bonus is (1000)*0.5%=$5

Task: write a SQL script that calculates the monthly bonus amount for each partner.

Data is in the link  [1]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17xo_gnu9nEwXuCNb8vBLEVrhPEKJaIRN/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112201519964034772995&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: use interval https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Comment: I'm trying, but it don't work select
 *
from
 transactions
where date=any (select date
    from
     transactions
    where 
     type='withdrawal' and date between date and (date - interval '3 month')) and type='deposit'
order by
 1,3,7

Comment: the lower date has to be on the left side of the and, when you use it like that it is invalid

Comment: Your `where` clause can never be satisfied. You essentially have ` type='withdrawal' and type='deposit'` but a column can never have 2 values at one time. If the value is 'withdrawal' then it is not 'deposit' so the AND condition is false. The same applies when value is 'deposit' then it is not 'withdrawal' so again the AND returns false. Also the date condition always returns TRUE. The `between` is inclusive of both ends so `date between (date - interval '3 month') and  date)` is always true since `date=date`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between worls only when the date left of the AND is lower tha the right.

So your code mus look like

```
select 
     * 
from 
    transactions 
where date=any (select 
date 
from 
transactions 
where type='withdrawal' 
and date between (date - interval '3 month') AND  date)  
and type='deposit' 
order by 1,3,7
```